# A question about convergence rate

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

We know that If  $k$ is constant. Then:
$O(|k| g)=O(g)$ and if $k$ is nonzero $f=O(g) \Rightarrow k f=O(g)$. I'm wondering for example, a numerical scheme's rate of convergence is $O(\Delta t)$ and if $k$ here is $T+\Delta t$, where $T$ is constant, can we still use this property and claim that $(T+\Delta t)O(\Delta t)=O(\Delta t)$?

Comment: Supposedly $\Delta t \to 0 $?

Comment: @zkutch Yes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume $\Delta t \to 0$, then $(T+\Delta t)O(\Delta t)$ is set of functions $f(\Delta t)(T+\Delta t)$, so

$$|f(\Delta t)(T+\Delta t)|\leqslant |f(\Delta t)T|+|f(\Delta t)\Delta t|\leqslant C |T| |\Delta t| +C|\Delta t|^2 \leqslant A|\Delta t| $$
for some constant $A$. So we can say $(T+\Delta t)O(\Delta t) \subset O(\Delta t)$.

For reverse let's assume, for simplicity $T>0$ and take $f(\Delta t) \in O(\Delta t)$, so $|f(\Delta t)| \leqslant C|\Delta t|$. Now if we consider $f(\Delta t) = g(\Delta t) (T+\Delta t)$, then for $g$ we have $g(\Delta t) = \frac{f(\Delta t)}{T+\Delta t}$ and we come to inequality
$$\left|  \frac{f(\Delta t)}{T+\Delta t} \right | \leqslant  \left|\frac{C\Delta t}{T+\Delta t} \right | \leqslant A|\Delta t|$$
for some constant $A$. So we can say $O(\Delta t) \subset (T+\Delta t)O(\Delta t)$. And your claim $(T+\Delta t)O(\Delta t)=O(\Delta t)$ is proved.